# python OpenSLL OverflowError

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a web scraper working with Scrapy. When I try and scrape an https site, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1291, in request
    parsedURI.originForm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1182, in _requestWithEndpoint
    d = self._pool.getConnection(key, endpoint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1071, in getConnection
    return self._newConnection(key, endpoint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1083, in _newConnection
    return endpoint.connect(factory)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 869, in connect
    timeout=self._timeout, bindAddress=self._bindAddress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 507, in connectSSL
    tlsFactory = tls.TLSMemoryBIOFactory(contextFactory, True, factory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 608, in __init__
    contextFactory.getContext()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 794, in getContext
    return self._webContext.getContext(self._hostname, self._port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/contextfactory.py", line 19, in getContext
    ctx.set_options(SSL.OP_ALL)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 753, in set_options

exceptions.OverflowError: integer 2147486719 does not fit '32-bit int'
```

There seems to be a bug fix here, https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/773 but I have the most recent version of cryptography (0.3).

Any ideas of what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the error is misleading. On windows 32, 2147486719 wouldn't fit 'long' either (because long is also 4 bytes).

To fix this, download latest cryptography code from https://github.com/pyca/cryptography, and then replace this line in ssl.py

```
long SSL_CTX_set_options(SSL_CTX *, long);
```

with

```
long SSL_CTX_set_options(SSL_CTX *, unsigned long);
```

Rebuild & install... and things should work just fine.